# Alternate SSH connection on GitLab.com Config File

Tags: ssh, gitlab

[Going through this article to overcome the blocked port 22.](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/)

[image]

They require you to edit the config file in the .ssh directory, but for the life of me I cannot find a config file inside the .ssh directory

C:\users\myuser\.ssh Only has my generated ssh keys in there. No config file.

Literally the only place I could find any resemblance of a ssh_config file is shown below, and tried updating that config but to no avail.

[image]

Does any one know where on earth do you find that config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C:\users\myuser.ssh** is the right place.

If the config file isn't there simply create it. the Following command in the .ssh folder for example.

```
touch config
```

And then put your config inside

Comment: Created it, but not working. How would git even know to look in there for any kind of config file If I just create it?

Comment: Its not git that will now but ssh. ssh will know because it's its configuration location. And git is using ssh to connect to your repo. Are you using git with ssh ? And you have create it and fill it I hope ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user43968 to putting me on the right track

So I got it to work

1. Create the file and add the connection settings in there.
2. Then, I used [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and updated the settings as follow

[image]

For the username and password, add the username and password to the proxy server. That was the main issue stopping me from cloning anything.